# Как сделать что бы контент аккордиона открывался в одном месте

Tags: javascript, html, css

подскажите плиз - столкнулся с необходимостью раскрытия аккордеона в одном месте. другими словами, нужно что бы при раскрытии "вкладки меню аккордиона" предыдущая (открытая) закрывалась, а та которая раскрывается становилась к примеру в позицию top: 0; Подобным образом работает поиск картинок в google - там аккордион при раскрытии центрируется, а как реализовать то что нужно мне не могу понять. если кто знает, заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: покажите свой код который реализовали.И я хочу уточнить вы хотите при клике поднять активный блок вверх?

Comment: Спасибо, большое за отзыв уже разобрался, всё гораздо проще чем я думал. Да именно поднять активный блок вверх. хочу поделиться кодом, но не знаю как это сделать, что бы его минимализировало...

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение к которому я пришел. Буду благодарен за конструктивную критику.

```
jQuery(function () {
    initAccordion();
});

function initAccordion() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '#accordionExample .btn-link', function (event) {
            $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 500);
        });
    });
};
```